# NSManagedObject subclass updating custom property - getting KVO errors

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject, cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing

EDIT: figured out that the NSNumber was a bad type to bind to. Using NSString instead solved the problem

I have a ToDo entity which has a to-one relationship ("title") with the ToDoTitle entity, and the relationship in reverse("todos") is to-many . i.e. a todo can have one title, but a title can have multiple todos.

Now I want to add a separate NSNumber on top of my NSManagedObject for count of the "incomplete todos" i.e. they have a todo.todoStatus == FALSE.

It looks like this:

```
@interface ToDoTitle : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * displayOrder;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSSet *todo; // this is saved in Core Data model
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *incompleteCount; // this isn't in the Core Data model
```

I can tweak the `incompleteCount` getter to return the correct count of items, and this works:

```
- (NSNumber *) incompleteCount {
    [self willAccessValueForKey:@"incompleteCount"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoStatus == FALSE"];
    NSSet *incomplete = [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"todo"] filteredSetUsingPredicate: predicate];
    [self didAccessValueForKey:@"incompleteCount"];

    return @([incomplete count]);
}
```

Now what I really use this for is for Cocoa Bindings, to display this number on a button. The binding works from the NSButton to a NSTableViewCell with the model key path = "objectValue.managedObject.incompleteCount.stringValue"

This also works fine, and displays the correct data initially. I also implement this in TodoTitle to keep track of changes to the 'todo' set:

```
+ (NSSet*) keyPathsForValuesAffectingIncompleteCount {
    return [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects: @"todo", nil];
}
```

so now when I add or delete ToDo objects, the count for each title gets updated correctly as well.

What I can't figure out how to update this `incompleteCount` when I update one of the todo object's `todoStatus`. I need to do something like this in the ToDo managed object:

```
- (void) setTodoStatus:(NSNumber *)todoStatus {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"todoStatus"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:todoStatus forKey:@"todoStatus"];

    if (todoStatus.boolValue == YES) {
        self.todotitle.incompleteCount = @(self.todotitle.incompleteCount.integerValue - 1);
    }

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"todoStatus"];

}
```

I get this error:

> 2014-08-03 22:27:26.632 CJ[9487:303] Cannot update for observer
>    for the key path
>   "incompleteCount.stringValue" from , most
>   likely because the value for the key "incompleteCount" has changed
>   without an appropriate KVO notification being sent. Check the
>   KVO-compliance of the ToDoTitle class.

with this stack trace:

```
2014-08-03 22:27:26.634 Contacts Journal[9487:303] (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b5c525c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8f25be75 objc_exception_throw + 43
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8b5c510c +[NSException raise:format:] + 204
        3   Foundation                          0x00007fff92c134b0 -[NSKeyValueNestedProperty object:withObservance:didChangeValueForKeyOrKeys:recurse:forwardingValues:] + 1003
        4   Foundation                          0x00007fff92ba6fd9 NSKeyValueDidChange + 166
        5   Foundation                          0x00007fff92babbe6 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 118
        6   CoreData                            0x00007fff88542b01 -[NSManagedObject didChangeValueForKey:] + 113
        7   CJ                    0x00000001000d664e -[ToDo setTodoStatus:] + 318
        8   CJ                    0x00000001000ff2a9 -[ToDo(ToDo_Category) updateStatusToComplete] + 345
```

I'm just not sure to update the incompleteTodos object in a KVO-compliant way. I've tried various things, like wrapping the call inside `willChangeValueForKey:` and `didChangeValueForKey:` but doesn't seem to help:

```
- (void) setTodoStatus:(NSNumber *)todoStatus {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"todoStatus"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:todoStatus forKey:@"todoStatus"];

    if (todoStatus.boolValue == YES) {
       [self.todotitle willChangeValueForKey:@"incompleteCount"];
       self.todotitle.incompleteCount = @(self.todotitle.incompleteCount.integerValue - 1);
       [self.todotitle didChangeValueForKey:@"incompleteCount"];
    }

    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"todoStatus"];

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I've also tried adding a custom setter in TodoTitle, with and without the willChange/didChange calls:

```
- (void) setIncompleteCount:(NSNumber *)incompleteCount_ {
    incompleteCount = incompleteCount_;
}
```

but still get the same problem.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that if I change `incompleteCount` type to an NSString instead of an NSNumber, and turn the integer into a string, it works fine! Must be some problem with NSNumber's stringValue not updating with the binding? I don't know. Wasted half a day on this!

Comment: Any way you could bind to `incompleteCount`-- the NSNumber object-- with `stringValue` as the keyPath?  I think you were trying to bind to the NSString object, but that NSString object is not really what you want to bind to... it's the NSNumber object.